# Flask Form sends all fields in the url

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a search field in my navbar as follows:

```
     <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="GET"  > 
            {{ barsearchform.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="input-group">
              {{ barsearchform.query(class="form-control rounded",placeholder="Search articles") }}
              {{ barsearchform.submit(class="btn btn-outline-primary") }}
            </div>
     </form>
```

but when submitted all the fields are shown in the url bar , even the submit button, like so

```
  http://localhost:5000/?csrf_token=IjlmMmU0NTg0MmE0N2E1NDBkOGRiOTZlMDk0MjYzNjRjZWI2Njc2YjUi.YZqHoQ.ka3sNHGTCWSQ_GvnOnwr4j86iHA&query=aaaaaaaa&submit=Search
```

the route handler

```
  @articles.route("/search/")
  def bar_search():
      if request.method == "GET":
          term = request.args.get('query')
          ...
          return render_template(...
```

what I would like is **http://localhost:5000/?query=aaaaaaaa**

Answer (score 0):

in a GET method everything goes in the url. You have some options

- rewrite the url at destination
- pass stuff to hide as headers (this might give you problems with CORS)
- use POST method and hide stuff in the body
- you could place things you don't want to send outside the `<form>`

Comment: the reason I want to use GET is to be able to share a search link, but it doesn't seem right to have the csrf token in it, and even the submit button !. all the searches and the videos I saw show only the query in the url using a from with get